# Is it possible to conditionally insert text via regex substitution in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have have several lines from a table that I’m converting from Excel to the Wiki format, and want to add link tags for part of the text on each line, if there is text in that field. I have started the converting job and come to this point:

```
|10.20.30.9||x|-||
|10.20.30.10||x|s04|Server 4|
|10.20.30.11||x|s05|Server 5|
|10.20.30.12|||||
|10.20.30.13|||||
```

What I want is to change the fourth column from, e.g., `s04` to `[[server:s04]]`. I do not wish to add the link brackets if the line is empty, or if it contains `-`. If that `-` is a big problem, I can remove it.

All my tries on regex to get anything from the line ends in the whole line being replaced.

Comment: You likely don't need a regex. You can simply search and replace "s04" with "[[server:s04]]", correct?

Comment: But I wish to add the text on all the lines where there is text in the same column as s04, and the colums before that may contain text, so a visual block does not work.

Comment: You should consider using `awk`, setting '|' as a field separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend the following substitution command.

```
:%s/^|\%([^|]*|\)\{3}\zs[^|-]\+\ze|/[[server:&]]/
```

Comment: Very nice! This is probably the easiest and best solution to the issue!

Comment: I noticed one problem. Any entry in column 4 containing one or more "-" would get a link surrounding the part up to the first "-". Since I descided to remove all entries with only a "-" the regex could be changed to: %s/^|\%([^|]*|\)\{3}\zs[^|]\+/[[server:&]]/

Comment: @user1410444:  I probably got this part of specification wrong.  To clarify the issue: Should the command ignore the lines where the fourth column *is* a hyphen, or where it *contains* a hyphen?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `awk` to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'|' '
{ 
  OFS = "|";
  if ($5 != "" && $5 != "-")
    $5 = "server:" $5;
  print $0
}'
```

*NOTE: I've edited this script since the first version. This current one, IMO is better.*

Then you can process it with:

```
cat $FILENAME | sh $AWK_SCRIPTNAME
```

The `-F'|'` switch tells `awk` to use `|` as a field separator. The `if/else` and `printf` statements are pretty self explanatory. It prints the fields, with 'server:' prepended to column 5, only if it is not `"-"` or `""`.

Why column 5 and not column 4?: Because you use `|` at the beginning of each record. So `awk` takes the 'first' field (`$1`) to be an empty string that it *believes* should have occured *before* this first `|`.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to do the job on the sample you give up there (with Vim):

```
%s/^|\%([^|]*|\)\{3}\zs[^|]*/\=(empty(submatch(0)) || submatch(0) == '-') ? submatch(0) : '[[server:'.submatch(0).']]'/
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!. I descided to remove the - in the field, making the substistution easier.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better to use awk as ArjunShankar writes, but this should work if you remove "-" ;) Didn't get it to work with it there.

```
:%s/^\([^|]*|\)\([^|]*|\)\([^|]*|\)\([^|]*|\)\([^|]\+|\)/\1\2\3\4[[server:\5]]/
```

It's just stupid though. The first 4 are identical (match anything up to | 4 times). Didn't get it to work with {4}. The fifth matches the s04/s05-strings (just requires that it's not empty, therefor "-" must be removed).

Comment: easier would be to use `\{3}` to match the first three. You can also use `[^-|][^|]*` to skip the case of just `-`.  Also, try using `\zs` to avoid consuming the first section completely: : `:%s/^\%(|[^|]*\)\{3}\)|\zs\([^-|][^|]*\)/[[server:\1]]/`

Comment: To avoid using a lot of groups try using `\zs` and `\ze`. In order to match only words (solvind the `-`issue) you can use the following regex: `\w\{1,}`

Comment: @MagnunLeno what is different about `\w\+` vs. `\w{1,}`?

Comment: @sehe, they're the same, I just have the habit to use `{1,}`. But, there is a huge difference between `\+` (or `{1,}`) and `{-1,}`. The first is a greedy version (matches as many as possible) of the second, which match as few as possible.

Comment: This regex put the | after field 4 inside the [[]] tag.

Comment: @user1410444: Oh, missed that. That was really stupid. Now I'm embarrassed. But using \zs and some other tricks others have mentioned was much nicer anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit more readability to the ideas given by others:

```
:%s/\v^%(\|.{-}){3}\|\zs(\w+)/[[server:\1]]/
```

Job done.

Note how {3} indicates the number of columns to skip. Also note the use of `\v` for *very magic* regex mode. This reduces the complexity of your regex, especially when it uses more 'special' characters than literal text.

Comment: Nice one! I've completely forgotten that we could use the {3} to reduce repetitions. Up vote for this!

Comment: This did not completely work. On some lines where the fourth field is empty, but there is text in the fifth, the fifth was put as the link.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 :1,$s/|\(s[0-9]\+\)|/|[[server:\1]]|/
```

assuming that your s04, s05 are always s and a number

Comment: mediawiki markup, so the replacment should be `|[[server:\1]]|`

Comment: Note that this will replace the first s04 in the following "|10.20.30.11|s04|x|s05|Server 5|".

Comment: @JohanSoderberg: Yes it will, but I assumed that the input is like the given example and therefor not containing s03 within the first columns. But you're right of course.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler substitution can be achieved with this:

```
%s/^|.\{-}|.\{-}|.\{-}|\zs\(\w\{1,}\)\ze|/[[server:\1]]/

   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   -> Match the first 3 groups (empty or not);
                       ^^^                -> Marks the "start of match";
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^     -> Match only if the 4th line contains letters numbers and `_` ([0-9A-Za-z_]);
                                     ^^^  -> Marks the "end of match";
```

If the `_`character is similar to `-`, can appear but must not be substituted, uset the following regex: `%s/^|.\{-}|.\{-}|.\{-}|\zs\([0-9a-zA-Z]\{1,}\)\ze|/[[server:\1]]/`